# How does marginalization of variables effect least squares SLAM energy function?

Tags: slam, computer-vision

Consider a simple example of Bundle Adjustment where I have robot and landmark poses $x = \left[ x_p \text{ } x_m\right]^T$ and measurements given by $z$, such that a simple factor graph can be generated with the nodes containing poses and edges containing the measurements. I'll have to solve for a non-linear least squares problem of the form $C(x) = \frac{1}{2}|| r(x) ||^2$ where $r(x)$ denotes the residuals.

I can implement and use any non-linear least squares optimization algorithm such as Gauss-Newton or use a popular library like ceres-solver.

**My question is**: Now suppose out of the state variables $x = \left[ a \text{ } b\right]^T$, I need to marginalize some variables $b$, while keeping the rest $a$. How do I apply this in terms of Gauss-Newton Algorithm and ceres-solver?

I understand the Gauss-Newton Algorithm and Schur Complement.
If the original covariance of the system is 
\begin{equation} K = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    A & C^T \\
    C & D
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Original Information 
\begin{equation} K^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \Lambda_{aa} & \Lambda_{ab} \\
    \Lambda_{ba} & \Lambda_{bb}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
Marginalized covariance $K_m = [A]$ and marginalized information $K_m^{-1} = A^{-1}$ where is $A$ is computed by the schur complement $A^{-1} = \Lambda_{aa} - \Lambda_{ab}\Lambda_{bb}^{-1}\Lambda_{ba}$.

Now, what do I do when new poses and measurements are added to the system and optimization is done?